# Joining two data frames by sequential column matching

Tags: r, dplyr, merge

Let's say I have two data frames like so:

```
test_1 = game_df = read.table(text = "id winner_name
1 Jon
2 Bob
3 Lucas
4 Marcus
5 Toad
6 Donkey", header = T)

test_2 = game_df = read.table(text = "id_1 id_2 loser_name
9 1 Henry
2 2 George
3 3 Bagel
4 4 Cat
5 5 Giraffe
7 6 Monkey", header = T)
```

What I want to do is to first is to `left_join` `test_1` on the `id = id_=1` match like so:

```
test_1 %>% left_join(test_2 %>% select(id_1, loser_name), by = c('id' = 'id_1'))
```

There will be certain NA matches (John, and Donkey)

```
  id winner_name loser_name
1  1         Jon       <NA>
2  2         Bob     George
3  3       Lucas      Bagel
4  4      Marcus        Cat
5  5        Toad    Giraffe
6  6      Donkey       <NA>
```

And then I'd like to use `id_2` as the matching column to fill the NA's, so I currently do something like this:

```
test_1 %>% left_join(test_2 %>% select(id_1, loser_name), by = c('id' = 'id_1')) %>%
  left_join(test_2 %>% select(id_2, loser_name), by = c('id' = 'id_2'))

  id winner_name loser_name.x loser_name.y
1  1         Jon         <NA>        Henry
2  2         Bob       George       George
3  3       Lucas        Bagel        Bagel
4  4      Marcus          Cat          Cat
5  5        Toad      Giraffe      Giraffe
6  6      Donkey         <NA>       Monkey
```

This seems to work, but it generates a bunch of duplicate columns with `x` and `y` suffixes. In my actual dataset, I have to go through this conditional matching approach through a ton of `id` matches, so it will generate a large number of duplicate columns, that I then have to manually deselect and rename.

The issue is that there are hundreds of columns in the actual `test_2` data.frame (loser_name, loser_country, loser_elo, loser_record, loser_win_rate), etc., so I'd need to manually specify the name and the columns to coalesce for each one. Furthermore, because I do this sequential id matching with more than one id, I'll have loser_name.x, loser_name.y, loser_name.z, and I don't know in advance how many suffixes there will be for each column.

Is there a simpler approach to this?

Comment: what is your expected output

Comment: Expected output is that last dataframe, except only display the results of the full column with no NAs (`loser_name.y`) and without the `.y` suffix. However, in my actual dataset I have hundreds of columns that are being matched, so manually renaming them all and deleting the incomplete columns is a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do a `coalesce` at the end

```
library(dplyr)
test_1 %>%
   left_join(test_2 %>% select(id_1, loser_name), by = c('id' = 'id_1')) %>%  
   left_join(test_2 %>% select(id_2, loser_name), by = c('id' = 'id_2')) %>%
   transmute(id, winner_name, loser_name = coalesce(loser_name.x, loser_name.y))
```

-output

```
   id winner_name loser_name
1  1         Jon      Henry
2  2         Bob     George
3  3       Lucas      Bagel
4  4      Marcus        Cat
5  5        Toad    Giraffe
6  6      Donkey     Monkey
```

---

If there are many 'id_' columns in 'test_2', here is an option

```
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
nm1 <- grep("id_", names(test_2), value = TRUE)
out <-  map(nm1, ~ test_2 %>% 
          select( -starts_with('id'), all_of(.x)) %>%
           left_join(test_1, ., by = setNames(.x, 'id'))) %>% 
           reduce(left_join, by = c("id", "winner_name")) 
out %>% 
  select(starts_with('loser')) %>% 
  split.default(str_remove(names(.), "\\..*")) %>% 
  map_dfc(~ invoke(coalesce, .)) %>% 
  bind_cols(test_1, .)
```

Comment: Thanks, Akrun. The issue is that there are hundreds of columns in the actual `test_2` data.frame (`loser_name`, `loser_country`, `loser_elo`, `loser_record`, `loser_win_rate`), etc., so I'd need to manually specify the name and the columns to coalesce for each one. Furthermore, because I do this sequential id matching with more than one id (`id_1`, `id_2`, `id_3`, `id_4`, etc.), I'll have `loser_name.x`, `loser_name.y`, `loser_name.z`, and I don't know in advance how many suffixes there will be.

Comment: @Parseltongue But you are doing only two `left_join` right (even with multiple columns?)

Comment: Well, for my specific use case right now there are only two left_joins, but later down the line I'd need to add `left_join(test_2 %>% select(id_3, loser_name), by = c('id' = 'id_3'))` and potentially another left_join for `id_4`.

Comment: Let me understand that `test_2` have all these `id_1`, `id_2`, `id_3`,  along with the loser_columns.. whereas `test_1` have only `id`

Comment: Correct. `test_1` contains the true, correct ID of a given player. `test_2` has a lot of `id` columns (`id_1`, `id_2`, `id_3`) that ideally should be the same as `test_1`'s `id` variable, but some databases incorrectly wrote down the `id`. So I'm trying basically a sequential matching approach ("first, try to match using id_1, if that didn't work, match using id_2, if that didn't work, match using id_3), etc.

Comment: @Parseltongue you may check the update.  I tried by creating more id columns and loser columns and it seems to work though

Comment: Nicely done! Thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

You can try joining test_1 on a molten (=long) version of test_2. Only workt if the order of the molten test_2 resembles the search-order of your id's..
Now you can have id_1, id_2, ..., id_100

```
library(data.table)
#make them data.tables
setDT(test_1)
setDT(test_2)

#join on molten set
test_1[melt(test_2, id.vars = "loser_name"), 
       loser_name := i.loser_name, 
       on = .(id = value)]

#    id winner_name loser_name
# 1:  1         Jon      Henry
# 2:  2         Bob     George
# 3:  3       Lucas      Bagel
# 4:  4      Marcus        Cat
# 5:  5        Toad    Giraffe
# 6:  6      Donkey     Monkey
```